# Missing Header data after DataTables Excel Export

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm looking to have export functionality on a webpage using datatables.
My table structure is as follows:

```
<table id="data-table" class="display table" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" class="center-align solid-left-border" style="border-bottom: none; text-decoration: underline; text-transform: uppercase; padding: 5px 18px;">
        Tier 2 Contributions Report
      </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th class="left-align solid-left-border" style="border-bottom: none; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: normal; font-weight: normal; padding: 5px 18px; font-size: 12.5px">
        Employer's FIle No/Registration No:
      </th>

      <th colspan="3" class="left-align solid-left-border" style="border-bottom: none; font-weight: normal; padding: 5px 18px; font-size: 12.5px; text-transform: uppercase;">
        <%= company.getSSNITRegistration() || '-' %>
      </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th class="left-align solid-left-border" style="border-bottom: none; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: normal; padding: 5px 18px; font-size: 12.5px;">
        Name of Employer:
      </th>

      <th colspan="3" class="left-align solid-left-border" style="border-bottom: none; font-weight: normal; padding: 5px 18px; font-size: 12.5px; text-transform: uppercase;">
        <%= company.getName() || '-' %>
      </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th class="left-align solid-left-border" style="border-bottom: none; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: normal; padding: 5px 18px; font-size: 12.5px;">
        Address of Employer:
      </th>

      <th colspan="3" class="left-align solid-left-border" style="border-bottom: none; font-weight: normal; padding: 5px 18px; font-size: 12.5px; text-transform: uppercase;">
        <%= company.getAddress() || '-' %>
      </th>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <th colspan="4" style="border-bottom: none;"></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th class="left-align">Social Sec. No.</th>
      <th class="left-align">Full Name</th>
      <th class="center-align">Basic Salary</th>
      <th class="right-align">Contribution (5%)</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>

  <tfoot>
   <tr>
     <th colspan="2" class="left-align">Totals</th>
     <th class="center-align"><%= addCommas(totals.basicSalary) %></th>
     <th class="right-align"><%= addCommas(totals.contribution) %></th>
   </tr>
  </tfoot>

  <tbody>   
    <% employees.forEach(function(employee) { %>
      <tr>
        <td class="left-align"><%= employee.ssnitNumber %></td>
        <td class="left-align"><%= employee.lastName + ', ' + employee.firstName + ' ' + employee.otherNames%></td>
        <td class="center-align"><%= addCommas(employee.basicSalary) %></td>
        <td class="right-align"><%= addCommas(employee.contribution) %></td>
      </tr>
    <% }) %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and js:

```
$('#data-table').DataTable( {
  "bPaginate": true,
  "bLengthChange": true,
  "bFilter": true,
  "bSort": false,
  "bInfo": true,
  "bAutoWidth": false,
  "dom": 'Bfrtip',
  "buttons": [
    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
  ]

});
```

Though exports work, for some reason only the last part of the header gets exported:

```
    <tr>
      <th class="left-align">Social Sec. No.</th>
      <th class="left-align">Full Name</th>
      <th class="center-align">Basic Salary</th>
      <th class="right-align">Contribution (5%)</th>
    </tr>
```

I've tried playing around with exportOptions, but not much luck there, and moreover, headers are exported by default.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question its possible to export any data(custom text, images) with data table export functionality with change in declaration as below.

```
table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "bProcessing"   :   true,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            customize: function ( doc ) {
                doc.content.splice( 0, 0, {
                    text: "Add your custom data here"
                } );
            }
        },
        'copyHtml5',
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5'
    ]
} );
```

For this DOM elements to work we need to include the below stylesheet and scripts

```
//Stylesheet
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">

//Scripts
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
```

**Note:** 
As you have asked for your custom header export in this example shows how to pass custom data we provided in "text" section(It will not export your extra headers automatically).

So please remove your first headers like "Tier 2 Contributions Report" and keep them outside table definition and add their values in "text" section

I have created Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/rbunuv9b/ for the same please have a look.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried getting it to work for excel but no luck.
Does this work for only pdfs?

Comment: As given on their site https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/pdfImage.html it has been shown for PDF only so i don't think its going to support other exports..